# Partitioning disk to install debian

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian

I am trying to install Debian 7.5.0 LXDE, using Graphical mode. I have some experience with installing Linux systems from before, I did it couple times with Ubuntu versions (Ubuntu, Xubutnu and Lubuntu). And it was simple, as I have just made separate partition for `root`(/), separate partition for `/home` (both formatted with `ext4`) and swap partition.

Now, I would like to install Debian LXDE linux. So, I have downloaded Debian Live ISO, burned it to DVD, boot up, chosen Graphical mode installation, and chosen same partitions that I had set up for previous Ubuntu linux, now for Debian. So, there was `/`(root-partition), `/home` partition and swap. I have also set for this partitions to be formatted during installation process. After installation process was done, system restarted and Login screen appeared. But when I type password (that I know is correct), I am getting message `Incorrect password, please try again`, and I am stucked there, never mind if its Xsession, LXDE or OpenBox selected.

Do I need to partition disk for Debian some other way, than I did, or this is some other issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling whole system again solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Boot the LiveCd, Mount your Debian hard disk and chroot to the mounted filesystem. You can then run passwd and your username and follow the input to change your password.